# Sharepoint Rest search assigned task query Issue

Tags: rest, search, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to get all the task assigned to the logged in user from the search rest query on the Sharepoint hosted app. Query is running fine and i am getting all the task that are assigned only to one user. If a Task is assigned to more than one user than i am not getting that item in my JSON object.

I am getting below query to extract all tasks:

```
SPAppWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
     var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
     var strParams = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == param) {
           return singleParam[1];
        }
     }
}

var restQueryUrl=SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='and(contenttype:equals(\"task\"),AssignedTo:equals(\"" + userTitle + "\"))'&selectproperties='Title,Created,StartDate,EndDate,AssignedTo,Status,RelatedItems,PercentComplete,Priority,Path,Url,Author'&rowlimit=1000";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Then I changed my query and removed equals().

```
AssignedTo:equals(\"" + userTitle + "\"))'

AssignedTo:(\"" + userTitle + "\"))'
```

Hope this will help you.